# How to make something like tile view in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make something like tiles; like in attached pic ( clickable image and label below), but I am new to XAML and don't know what control should I use.I tried Grid, but I think there is better solution. Items would be added and managed at runtime.

[image: What i want to do]

Comment: you can use a list view with edited item template.

Comment: this will help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18561/Custom-ListBox-Layout-in-WPF

Comment: I would go with an [ItemsControl](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) - max. freedom :D

Comment: Take a look at this answer, teaching how to use UniformGrid (or WrapPanel if you like) as the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl. That should be the right way of doing it:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8243277/401828

Answer (score 2):

Look into using a [UniformGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx) for it is designed to evenly space items in a row/colum type format. Then just use a filled in border and a textbox. I leave it up to you to add an image, a button, whatever is needed inside the border to achieve the desired effect.

[image]

```
<UniformGrid  Height="100" Width="120">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="BorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Brown"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Name="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Wheat"/> 
        </Style>                
    </UniformGrid.Resources>
    <Border><TextBlock Text="Pizza"/></Border>
    <Border><TextBlock Text="Pizza"/></Border>
    <Border><TextBlock Text="Pizza"/></Border>
    <Border><TextBlock Text="Pizza"/></Border>
</UniformGrid>
```

Please note that the UniformedGrid can be dynamically loaded with a templated items like any other control. The demo I have makes it look like its static and I don't want to give it that impression.

Comment: How can it be dynamically loaded? It does not have a itemsource.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this style,

```
<WrapPanel Height="320" Width="350">
<WrapPanelResources>
<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Grid Height="150" Width="100">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Background="Brown" Grid.Row="0">
                            </Border>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Pizza" Foreground="Red" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</WrapPanelResources>
            <ContentControl/>
            <ContentControl/>
            <ContentControl/>
            <ContentControl/>
            <ContentControl/>
            <ContentControl/>
        </WrapPanel>
```

Please don't forgot to mark as answer

Comment: I always find it tacky to tell people "remember to mark as answer".

Answer (score 0):

You know mahapps.metro? I suggest you use if you want to follow the path of tiles, they have pretty much everything when it comes to metro style for WPF.

http://mahapps.com/controls/tile.html

hope that helps.