# WPF binding to 2D array

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've been learning WPF and MVVM. I am trying to create a chess game. I have the game state represented as a 2D (8x8) array of pieces. The board is displayed as a UniformGrid of 64 elements. Everytime the game state changes, I loop through the game state array and update each square on the displayed board accordingly. Is there a better (more WPF) way to do this? I thought I could somehow bind each of the squares of the displayed board to the game state and define a value convertor that would access the array but I don't really know how to do that. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I would suggest to use the UniformGrid as ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl, and bind the ItemsSource property of the ItemsControl to a collection of 64 cell/field data objects. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243277/1136211. The field data item class would expose a set of properties with change notification that determine the state of a field. Bind to those properties in the ItemTemplate. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe switch to using ObservableCollection and bind it with, say a ListBox's ItemsSource property. also Consider extending the collection class to support 2d indexer so that you can manipulate cells the same way you did with the 2d array:

```
public class ObservableCollectionC<T> : ObservableCollection<T>{
    public ObservableCollectionC(IEnumerable<T> p) : base(p){ }
    public T this[int m, int n]{
        get  { return this[m*8+n]; }
        set  { this[m*8+n] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why ObservableCollection when the number of elements is fixed?

Comment: @Clemens you're right ObservableCollection is overkill. so List<T> would be the most basic class that has the indexer right?