# How to add a border to cells in UniformGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am creating a program to simulate turn-based battles like in DND and similar board and computer games. This is my first time working with XAML, I studied a lot of information and came to the conclusion that UniformGrid is best suited for the playing field, since the size can be edited by the user. I can't figure out how to add borders to cells

I searched the entire Internet and can't find any information. Maybe I chose the wrong type of grid, but then I don't understand at all what is better for my purpose

Comment: You would use the UniformGrid as ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl, e.g. as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243277/1136211). The border around the individual items would be declared in the ItemTemplate. For more info, see [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Only squares - no hexes? And are you animating one cell to another?

Comment: yes, only squares. I don't quite know how to implement animation yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an sample, You need play around a little of what type of control you want to use in uniform grids accordingly.

In this sample I am using rectangle and label inside uniform grid.
In MainWindow.xml, Paste below code -

```
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="400"  Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <UniformGrid x:Name="BoardGame" Margin="5">
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="6" MouseDown="L1_MouseDown" Stroke="DarkBlue" Name="l1" Fill="Green"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  StrokeThickness="6" Stroke="DarkBlue" Name="l2" Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
        <Label BorderThickness="6" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Teal"  Name="l3" ></Label>
        <Label BorderThickness="6" BorderBrush="Black"  Background="Yellow" Name="l4"></Label>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

In MainWindow.cs, Paste below code -

```
 private void L1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        l3.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Purple;
        l4.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.DodgerBlue;
    }
```

[image: SampleImage]